# How to make bash script stop if command responds with certain string?

Tags: command-line

I was wondering if it was possible to add a one line code to a bash script where it'll stop if the terminal says "Failed to load".

Right now I have the bash script involving melt to combine videos but sometimes a video won't be found which messes up the entire process. I then have to manually scroll way up until I find "Failed to load" and sometimes it's so far up I can't find it anymore.

I was wondering if there was a way so that if the terminal (or melt) responds with a line that contains "Failed to load" the script stops right then and there and does not continue. Or, at the least, have a way where it can output lines that say "Failed to load" into a .txt file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *pipe* a program's standard output to another program that passes it through, but quits when it matches a particular pattern. The first program *should* terminate when the pipe collapses.

To illustrate:

```
$ { printf '%.0sOK\n' {1..10}; printf 'failed to load\n'; printf '%.0sOK\n' {1..10}; } | sed '/failed to load/q'
OK
OK
OK
OK
OK
OK
OK
OK
OK
OK
failed to load
```

The method may need tweaking if the `failed to load` message is written to the standard error stream rather than the standard output stream:

```
somecommand 2>&1 | sed '/failed to woad/q'
```

ex.

```
melt "a/VID1.mkv" "a/VID2.mkv" -consumer avformat:/output/output.mkv acodec=libmp3lame vcodec=libx264 2>&1 | sed '/Failed to load/q'
```

---

If the command is part of a script, and you want to exit the script when this happens, then at least with GNU sed you can tell it to quit with a specific *exit code* which you may then test and act upon accordingly. For example

```
melt "a/VID1.mkv" "a/VID2.mkv" -consumer avformat:/output/output.mkv acodec=libmp3lame vcodec=libx264 2>&1 | sed '/Failed to load/q3'

if [ $? -eq 3 ]; then
  echo "Aborting concatenation" >&2
  exit 3
fi
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working unfortunately, this is what i tried to use:
`{ melt "a/VID1.mkv" "a/VID2.mkv"  -consumer avformat:/output/output.mkv acodec=libmp3lame vcodec=libx264; } 2>&1 | sed '/Failed to load/q'` and it still continued passed the Failed to load

Comment: @user2406786 the command grouping isn't necessary in your case (I only used it to synthesize output). Please try with plain `melt "a/VID1.mkv" "a/VID2.mkv" -consumer avformat:/output/output.mkv acodec=libmp3lame vcodec=libx264 2>&1 | sed '/Failed to load/q'`

Comment: That was it! Seems to be working flawless now for one line. Only other thing is it seems that in a bash txt file, it'll continue onto the next command in the list instead of just halting where it fails and stopping there.

Comment: @user2406786 please see edit for a suggestion about how to handle that